# gnuplot automatically orders data?

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data series:

```
2.72121 -1326.8380227810
2.81569 -1326.8407684060
2.91018 -1326.8428301680
3.00466 -1326.8448265650
3.09915 -1326.8470902260
3.19364 -1326.8497826100
3.28812 -1326.8530603940
3.38261 -1326.8571516770
3.47710 -1326.8628214990
3.57158 -1326.8694360090
3.66607 -1326.8759488230
3.76056 -1326.8820177910
3.85504 -1326.8875129030
3.94953 -1326.8923946780
4.04401 -1326.8966652370
4.13850 -1326.9003601490
4.23299 -1326.9035228070
```

and

```
4.23299   -1326.9035228070
4.13850   -1326.9003601490
4.04401   -1326.8966652370
3.94953   -1326.8923946780
3.85504   -1326.8875129030
3.76056   -1326.8820177910
3.66607   -1326.8759488230
3.57158   -1326.8694360090
3.47710   -1326.8628214990
3.38261   -1326.8571516770
3.28812   -1326.8530603940
3.19364   -1326.8497826100
3.09915   -1326.8470902260
3.00466   -1326.8448265650
2.91018   -1326.8428301680
2.81569   -1326.8407684060
2.72121   -1326.8380227810
```

which are the same data series but in reverse order. That's for the first series:

[image: Plot of first series]

and that's for the second one:

[image: Plot for the second series]

The full gnuplot code is:

```
set loadpath 'C:\Users\sjojungfrun\Programs\gnuplot\palettes'

load 'parula.pal'
set lmargin 10

unset key
set xtics font 'arial,16'
set ytics font 'arial,16'
set grid ytics

e_kcal = 627.509391
b_angs = 0.52918
stats "reverse_scan_coord.dat" nooutput
e_min = STATS_min_y

plot "reverse_scan_coord.dat" u ($1 * b_angs):(($2 - e_min) * e_kcal) w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc 11 #smooth csplines
```

I am using the Windows Version 5.0 patchlevel 5 of gnuplot.

Am I doing something wrong? I am really surprised about this auto-ordering feature.

Comment: Gnuplot doesn't reorder anything - the data points define the same curve, it doesn't matter whether it is traced/drawn on the canvas from "left-to-right" or vice versa, the "visual" output is the same...

Comment: Thanks @ewcz for your answer. I don't understand what you mean it doesn't matter if it's drawn left-to-right or vice versa though. 

Indeed my question is precisely about that, I want to reverse the order of the initial plot and for that, I reverse the order of the points to plot, but find out that gnuplot renders still the same output. Why is that, why gnuplot disregard the order in which I put the points and renders always the same graph?

I could get what I want with the option reverse from xrange, but still I would like to understand this behaviour of gnuplot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reverse the xrange, the x-values are ranged from smaller/less positive to larger/more positive.
By default, gnuplot connects points in the plot that were neighboring data points in the data file.
In your case one can thus indeed say that the graph is drawn from right to left, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That piece of info was missing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is answered and OP's misunderstanding is clarified, let me add some code for creating a plot which would satisfy OP's initial understanding, i.e. gnuplot would **automatically** adjust the axis direction depending on the direction of the data.
So, strictly speaking, this is not an answer, but an addition which might be useful to somebody for some (very special) cases.
Well, typically, either you know beforehand what direction your data has or you always want to plot it with either increasing (`noreverse`) or decreasing (`reverse`) x-values.

What the code does: checking the first and last datapoint and if the last one is smaller than the first one it sets the axis direction to `reverse` otherwise to `noreverse`. If I overlooked a simple gnuplot option for this, please let me know.

**Code:**

```
### automatically set axis in same direction as data
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
2.72121 -1326.8380227810
2.81569 -1326.8407684060
2.91018 -1326.8428301680
3.00466 -1326.8448265650
3.09915 -1326.8470902260
3.19364 -1326.8497826100
3.28812 -1326.8530603940
3.38261 -1326.8571516770
3.47710 -1326.8628214990
3.57158 -1326.8694360090
3.66607 -1326.8759488230
3.76056 -1326.8820177910
3.85504 -1326.8875129030
3.94953 -1326.8923946780
4.04401 -1326.8966652370
4.13850 -1326.9003601490
4.23299 -1326.9035228070
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
4.23299   -1326.9035228070
4.13850   -1326.9003601490
4.04401   -1326.8966652370
3.94953   -1326.8923946780
3.85504   -1326.8875129030
3.76056   -1326.8820177910
3.66607   -1326.8759488230
3.57158   -1326.8694360090
3.47710   -1326.8628214990
3.38261   -1326.8571516770
3.28812   -1326.8530603940
3.19364   -1326.8497826100
3.09915   -1326.8470902260
3.00466   -1326.8448265650
2.91018   -1326.8428301680
2.81569   -1326.8407684060
2.72121   -1326.8380227810
EOD

DirectionCheck(data,colX) = \
    sprintf('stats %s u (column(0)==0 ? x0=column(%d):x1=column(%d)) nooutput; \
    if (x0>x1) { set xrange[:] reverse } \
    else       { set xrange[:] noreverse }',data,colX,colX)

set multiplot layout 2,1
    set ytic 0.02

    SetDirection = DirectionCheck('$Data1',1)
    @SetDirection
    plot $Data1 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"

    SetDirection = DirectionCheck('$Data2',1)
    @SetDirection
    plot $Data2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]